# How can I bend an edge into a self-referencing circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge, tikz-path

I want to model the behaviour described by something like the following arrow using draw:

```
\draw[->] (zero.north) 
   .. controls +(left:7mm) and +(up:15mm)
   .. (zero.north);
```

But since I need to add a label to that arrow I'd prefer to use an edge. How can I bend an edge so that self-referencing nodes look acceptable:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (zero) [circle, draw] at (0,0) {z0};
    \draw[->] (-1, 0)-- (zero);
    \path[-stealth]
        (zero) edge[bend=???] node[above] {b} (zero);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (zero) [circle, draw] at (0,0) {z0};
    \draw[->] (-1, 0)-- (zero);
    \path[-stealth] (zero) edge[loop] node[above] {b} ();
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Above code id borrowed from drawings of automaton. In general you ca similar loop obtain with:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (zero) [circle, draw] at (0,0) {z0};
    \draw[->] (-1, 0)-- (zero);
    \path[-stealth] (zero) edge[out=45,in=135,looseness=20] node[above] {b} (zero);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** With this code you have more options to control of loop size (width, height) and   will get:

[image]

Comment: and that looks significantly better than anything I could've cooked with arrows... thanks :)

Comment: If you change (zero) to (zero.north), the loop gets tighter.